# Elasticsearch https cors enabled but still getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, http, elasticsearch, cors

I have enabled the settings for cors in my index called myIndex, here are the settings for it. But I when I try to pull the data from elasticsearch with some simple Javascript where the cors headers are set I get the error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://elasticSearchDomain.com:9200/myIndex/_search/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

I am running the Javascript by include it as a script that run when I open an html page through a python server.

```
{
      "state": "open",
      "settings": {
        "index": {
          "http": {
            "cors": {
              "allow-credentials": "true",
              "enabled": "true",
              "allow-origin": "*"
            }
          },
          "creation_date": "1461087830891",
          "number_of_shards": "5",
          "number_of_replicas": "1",
          "version": {
            "created": "1070499"
          },
          "uuid": "2JeIgB7IRs6_DzEb6PLx-w"
        }
      },
      "mappings": {
        "tx": {
          "properties": {
            "next": {
              "format": "dateOptionalTime",
              "type": "date"
            },
            "eid": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "95percent_time": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "total_count": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "failure_count": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "pool_id": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "pool_name": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "failure_rate": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "report_time": {
              "format": "dateOptionalTime",
              "type": "date"
            },
            "txn_type": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "status_default": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "txn_name": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "frequency_type": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "status_2": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "status_1": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "avg_time": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "datacenter_id": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "datacenter_name": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "server_type": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aliases": [

      ]
    }
```

Here is my Javascript that Im trying to use to pull data from elasticsearch

```
var url = "http://elasticSearchDomain.com:9200/myIndex/_search/";
var method = "POST";
var postData = '{"query": { "filtered": { "query": { "query_string": { "query": "*", "analyze_wildcard": true } }, "filter": { "bool": { "must": [ { "query": { "query_string": { "query": "*", "analyze_wildcard": true } } }, { "range": { "report_time": { "gte": 1458409392443, "lte": 1461001392443 } } } ], "must_not": [] } } } }, "size": 0, "aggs": { "2": { "date_histogram": { "field": "report_time", "interval": "12h", "pre_zone": "-07:00", "pre_zone_adjust_large_interval": true, "min_doc_count": 1, "extended_bounds": { "min": 1458409392443, "max": 1461001392443 } }, "aggs": { "3": { "terms": { "field": "pool_name", "size": 20, "order": { "_count": "desc" } } } } } } }';

// You REALLY want async = true.
// Otherwise, it'll block ALL execution waiting for server response.
var async = true;

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// specifies how the HTTP response will be handled. 
request.onload = function () {

   // You can get all kinds of information about the HTTP response.
   var status = request.status; // HTTP response status, e.g., 200 for "200 OK"
   var data = request.responseText; // Returned data, e.g., an HTML document.
}

request.open(method, url, async);
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

// Actually sends the request to the server.
request.send(postData);
```

Answer (score 7):

For some specificity (and for anyone having trouble with the regex part), I had to add these configurations in elasticsearch.yml:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: /https?:\/\/(localhost)?(127.0.0.1)?(:[0-9]+)?/
```

Not perfect regex, but my search app works now.

Comment: bro I want to allow only two links to enter in "allow origin". Can you tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Those are not index specific settings.

The `cors` settings should be placed in the `elasticsearch.yml` config file of every node in your ES cluster and the cluster restarted. See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#_settings_2) more about this.

Comment: You don't understand. The ES nodes storing your index need to have that, not the index itself.

Comment: I am not creating my index with an elasticsearch.yml config file though...I am doing a simple curl -XPUT "http://elasticSerarchDomain:9200/myIndex/" -d'
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "http": {
        "cors": {
.....

Comment: I would suggest reading a bit of documentation for Elasticsearch, you are missing some basic understanding of the product.

Comment: I think youre saying the cors level configurations are set for http://elasticSearchDomain.com:9200 and not my specific index. Correct? Sorry I am working with someone's ES cluster, not one i created myself.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You need that in that someone else's cluster.